# Using pgfmath in draw options

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I would like to set `draw` options  in `tikz` depending on some `pgfmath` calculations. More specifically, I would like to draw or not draw an edge depending on some value in an array.

This works fine if the calculations can be executed outside the actual `\draw` command, as in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle, inner sep=0mm,minimum size=1mm,draw}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,7}{
    \node (\i) at (\i,0) {\i};
}

\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(array({1,0,0,0,1,1},\i-1)==1, "black", "none")}
    \draw[draw=\pgfmathresult] (\i) -- (\the\numexpr\i+1\relax);
} 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in certain situations (for instance when using `grow cyclic`, as below), it is not obvious how to execute the calculation outside the `\draw` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow cyclic,circle,sibling angle=30,draw,
    level 1/.style={level distance=3cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=60},
    every node/.style={inner sep=0mm,minimum size=1mm,draw}]

    \node (Ac) {$u$} child foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
        node (\i) {\i} %edge from parent[draw=\pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(array({1,0,0,0,1,1},\i-1)==1, "black", "none")}\pgfmathresult];
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The commented part is an attempt of performing the calculation in situ, however this produces an error message (I suspect that `tikz` does not like that `\pgfmathparse` is not expandable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use package `etoolbox`
- added a 7th number to the array to match the size
- created style `myline` that gets the array and `\i` as parameters, and sets style `mylineB`, which is used afterwards (with `/.append style`).

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow cyclic,circle,sibling angle=30,draw,
    level 1/.style={level distance=3cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=60},
    every node/.style={inner sep=0mm,minimum size=1mm,draw},
    myline/.code 2 args={
        \pgfmathparse{array({#1},#2-1)}
        \ifnumequal{\pgfmathresult}{1}{%
            \tikzset{mylineB/.style={draw=black}}
        }{
            \tikzset{mylineB/.style={draw=none}}
        },
    },
    myline/.append style={mylineB},
]

    \node (Ac) {$u$} child foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
        node (\i) {\i} edge from parent[myline={1,0,0,0,1,1,0}{\i}]
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Creating a new style to solve the problem is something I would never have come up with, nor known how to do. 
Just out of interest, do you know the reason why this works while just using `pgfmathparse` in place fails? What difference does it make to `tikz` that the computation is "hidden" in the style rather than invoked in situ?

Comment: If you just put the whole thing in `myline/.style` it should not make any difference (and would not work with the current code). But here I used the key handler `.code` which interprets everything afterwards as normal LaTeX code and not as a style. For more information have a look into the documentation of [tikz/pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) Part VII Utilities.